# PHP String Replacement Not Working Properly

Tags: php, string

Here is my PHP code,

```
$string = 'https://www.mydomain.lk/';
$wordlist = array("http://", "www.", "https://", "/");

foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}

echo $string2 = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
```

I want to remove last "/" from $string.
so i add the "/" to $wordlist array, but its not working.

can somebody help me to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try using a different regex delimiter.

Comment: are you just trying to get `mydomain.lk` from `https://www.mydomain.lk/` ?

Comment: What should happen with a host like "something.domain.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to only replace `/` at the end of the string, so you need a `$`, like `/$`, but `preg_quote` would end up escaping the `$`.

The best way to remove a trailing `/` is using rtrim, like Sudhir suggested. Alternatively you could remove the `preg_quote` loop and just use regular expressions in your `$wordlist`:

```
$string = 'https://www.mydomain.lk/';
$wordlist = array("#https?://#", "#www\.#", "#/$#");

echo $string2 = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for the most part you wish to extract the hostname:

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Removing the leading `www.` can then be done separately.

```
preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$string = 'https://www.mydomain.lk/';
echo rtrim($string, '/'); //gives --> https://www.mydomain.lk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$url= 'https://www.mydomain.lk/';
echo $newurl = rtrim($url,"/");
```

Output like this format

```
https://www.mydomain.lk
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$string = 'https://www.mydomain.lk/';
$uri = parse_url($string);
$domain = str_replace("www.", "", strtolower($uri['host']));
echo $domain;
```